# Update Permissions User Roles & Permissions using multiple checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am making a project in which their are multiple users with different roles & permissions. Each user according to his role have permissions to (access, create, update,  delete). I have made a piece of code but whenever I try to update a role permissions it doesn't update the right table columns.

**#PERMISSIONS table structure**
[image]

**#PERMISSIONS FORM**

```
<form id="updatePermissionForm">

    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $role_id ?>" name="role_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="update_role" name="action">

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped custom-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="fw-bolder">Module Permission</th>
                    <th class="text-center fw-bolder">Accès</th>
                    <th class="text-center fw-bolder">Ecrire</th>
                    <th class="text-center fw-bolder">Modifier</th>
                    <th class="text-center fw-bolder">Supprimer</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($permissions as $prm) : ?>                                        
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <i class="ti-folder"></i> <?= moduleName($prm->module_id);?> 
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?= $prm->module_id ?>" name="module_id[]" >
                        </td>       
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <input class="access_module" type="checkbox" <?= ($prm->can_access) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="can_access[]" value="<?= $prm->can_access ?>">
                        </td>                
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="checkbox" <?= ($prm->can_create) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="can_create[]" value="<?= $prm->can_create ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <input type="checkbox" <?= ($prm->can_update) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="can_update[]" value="<?= $prm->can_update ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <input  type="checkbox" <?= ($prm->can_delete) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="can_delete[]" value="<?= $prm->can_delete ?>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="m-t-20 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="updatePermissionBtn" type="submit" >Sauvegarder</button>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

[image]

**#AJAX**

```
$(document.body).on('submit',  "#updatePermissionForm", function(e){
    e.preventDefault()     
    
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: `ajax/roles/roles_actions.php`,
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",

        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#updatePermissionBtn").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#updatePermissionBtn").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>  Sauvegarde en cours ...');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#updatePermissionBtn").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#updatePermissionBtn").html("Sauvegader");

            if (response.status == 1) {
                Swal.fire("Succès!", response.message, "success");
                
            } else {                            
                Swal.fire("Attention!", response.message, "error");
            }
        },
    });
});
```

**#roles_actions.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
     if($_POST['action'] == 'update_role'){
      
        foreach ($_POST['module_id'] as $key => $value) {

            $query = "UPDATE `permissions` SET
                            can_access=:can_access,
                            can_create=:can_create,
                            can_update=:can_update,
                            can_delete=:can_delete
                            
                        WHERE role_id=:role_id 
                        AND   module_id=:module_id
            ";

            $can_access = empty($_POST['can_access'][$value]) ? 0 : 1;
            $can_create = empty($_POST['can_create'][$value]) ? 0 : 1;
            $can_update = empty($_POST['can_update'][$value]) ? 0 : 1;
            $can_delete = empty($_POST['can_delete'][$value]) ? 0 : 1;

            $stmt = $PDO->prepare($query);  
           
            $stmt->bindParam(':can_access', $can_access, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':can_create', $can_create, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':can_update', $can_update, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':can_delete', $can_delete, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':role_id'   , $_POST['role_id']   , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':module_id' ,$_POST['module_id'][$key] , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            if($stmt){    
                $response['status'] = 1;
                $response['message'] = 'Permission du rôle ont été mise à jour avec succès!';
            }
        }
    }

}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Did I missed something here?

Comment: I think you are mixing up key and value in your form values. I would rather index the array of permissions by the module_id instead. In your roles_actions atm you try to access `$_POST['can_access'][$value]` while it should be `$_POST['can_access'][$key] `.  Changing the form field generation would make that a bit clearer.

Comment: I've changed the $_POST['can_access'][$value] to $_POST['can_access'][$key] but still same result. The query doesn't update the right fields!

What do you mean by changing the form field generation?
The form I made it not well presented?

Comment: In your loop you create form fields like this: `module_id[]`, `can_create[]`, so you rely on the order of this data, eg `module_id[0]` being the module_id for `can_create[0]`, I would either create a structure like this: `modules[<?= $prm->module_id ?>][id]`, `modules[<?= $prm->module_id ?>][id][can_create]`. Then you know $_POST['modules'] keys are the modules and everything inside is the permissions for that module.

Comment: Can you please make an example? because I really didn't get it :\

Comment: See verjas answer, it's pretty much what I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change two things in your solution:

1. in the `<form>` change how you structure your `name` attributes, from this:

`<input ... name="can_update[]" value="<?= $prm->can_update ?>">`

to something like this:

`<input ... name="permission[<?= $prm->module_id ?>][can_update]" value="1">`

which will produce something like this (e.g. module_id = 2):

`<input type="checkbox" checked name="permission[2][can_update]" value="1">`

and will be accessed in php via `$_POST['permission'][2]['can_update']=1`

2. Then in the `roles_actions.php`:

Change how you search for permissions in `$_POST`:

```
<?php
...

foreach ($_POST['module_id'] as $module_id) {
    ...
    $can_update = empty($_POST['permission'][$module_id]['can_update']) ? 0 : 1;
    ...
```